# ¿Cómo extraer la fecha de un JSON en MongoDB? - MEAN STACK

Tags: nodejs, angular, mongodb, express

Tengo un modelo de datos al cual le agregué una propiedad llamada **timestamps** esto me permite guardar la fecha de creación y actualización de un objeto (lo hace automático). Cuando un nuevo objeto se crea me deja el siguiente JSON:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5dd05db41f21a315e465d6de"),
"name" : "Juan Carlos",
"email" : "juan@gmail.com",
"password" : "$2a$10$HrpAhaDy0ATl07Jq2cPj3OJ97HgVD16rv6LAPDlMMfpEtj11I4HaO",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-16T20:36:04.608Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-16T20:36:04.608Z"),
"__v" : 0}
```

En Angular lo llamo de una manera fácil lo que es la fecha, pero me trae toda la información, algo así: **2019-11-16T20:36:04.608Z** lo que yo quiero es extraer esa fecha o información de una manera más limpia, como por ejemplo:

**2019-11-16**

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a como hacer eso?

Comment: Tienes varias alternativas, como extraerla ya formateada desde la consulta a mongodb (con aggregation + dateToString) o directamente con el dateformat de javascript tras la consulta (ya sea node o en el cliente al mostrarlo). Hay miles de ejemplos de esto último.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para poder mostrar las fechas como tú quieras, tienes que user las pipes de Angular, en concreto una que se llama **DatePipe** la cual tiene un montón de funcionalidades que parsean fechas.

Si no te interesase ninguna de las que te proporciona el pipe, podrías desarrollar tu propio pipe parseando la fecha a tu gusto.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes utilizar el DatePipe [Ejemplo DatePipe Angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/exampledatepipe)

Si quieres más información de los métodos que tiene DatePipe te dejo el enlace a la documentación de Angular [Documentación DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: Increíble, muchísimas gracias, no conocía este método para trabajar los formatos de fecha, profundizare más en ello. Lo que si noto es que me muestra la fecha actual y no la fecha que mi objeto tiene guardado. Ya cree una variable a la que le paso ese datos especifico y aún así me muestra la fecha actual.

Comment: Tienes que aplicar los formatos a la variable que almacena la fecha, yo hice el ejemplo con Date.now() que se encarga de mostrar la fecha actual así que si has utilizado el ejemplo estarás cogiendo la fecha actual.

Comment: Tarde en entender como usar la pipe y resultó ser más sencillo de lo que ya era. Ya quedó, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, considera agregar un ejemplo de uso con su respectiva salida, eso generará mayor calidad en el contenido. Igual tienes mi +1. ;)

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, lo haré en cuanto tenga un hueco y actualizaré la respuesta :)

Comment: Siento que los pipes son una base de Angular, cuidado ahí Carlos.